# ISBN Checker- No Loops

Tags: java, isbn

I'm trying to make a ISBN checker but it's not working. An example would be the user inputs 013601267 and return 0136012671. I'm not understanding what the problem is. No loops.
Any help would be great.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ISBN{
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter 9 digit ISBN");
    //variables//
    int d1=in.nextInt();
    int d2=in.nextInt();
    int d3=in.nextInt();
    int d4=in.nextInt();
    int d5=in.nextInt();
    int d6=in.nextInt();
    int d7=in.nextInt();
    int d8=in.nextInt();
    int d9=in.nextInt();
     int d10=(d1*1+d2*2+d3*3+d4*4+d5*5+d6*6+d7*7+d8*8+d9*9) %11;
    //keyboard


    if (d10==10){
    System.out.print("ISBN"+d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6+d7+d8+d9+"X");}
    else if(d10 !=10); {
    System.out.print("ISBN"+d10);}
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The integer input would be 0136067. The out put would be an 1 on the end or an x.

Comment: and what *does* happen instead?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: The problem is `nextInt()`.  It returns a number that can consist of several digits.  I'd recommend using `next()` instead, or maybe `nextLine()`, both of which return a `String`.  You can then examine the individual characters of the result.

Comment: What you describe is not a checker, it's a checkdgit generator. Understand the task before you start programming. The `if(d10 !=10);` part is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

When someone enters their ISBN, are they entering it with spaces in between?
`nextInt()` will retrieve the integers separated by spaces, so it is likely that `d1` is receiving the entire nine integers.

If you are entering them one at a time, then it should work.

Either enter the digits with spaces in between them, or each on their own line. `Scanner` will take care of the rest.

Note:

If you don't want the user to have to enter the digits one-by-one, try taking their input as:

`String digits = in.nextLine();`

You can reference each digit in that string with `digits.charAt(0)` etc.

```
int d1=Integer.parseInt("" + digits.charAt(0));
```

and so on. This will convert the single character `digits.charAt(0)` to your integer for the formula.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution isn't _friendly_... The user should have the opportunity to enter the whole input without the spaces (new lines, etc...)

Comment: @zlakad Is this better? The first part wasn't as much of a solution, as much as pointing Tillix to the problem so that they could stop being stuck

Comment: thank you @DawoodibnKareem I should have checked those before I posted. They should work now